# MySQL: fixing data using other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fix data in table "tag" using table "tag2",

by match "tag.id" and "tag2.id" and if matched replace "tag2.name" with "tag.name" in "tag" table,

tables structures:

tag:

```
id     name
1     test
2     test
3     test
4     Tom hancks
5     test
6     amazon
7     car
8     BMW
9     search
```

tag2:

```
id     name
1     Google
2     yahoo
3     Microsoft
4     Tom hancks
5     facebook
```

to return "tag" table like this:

tag:

```
id     name
1     Google
2     yahoo
3     Microsoft
4     Tom hancks
5     facebook
6     amazon
7     car
8     BMW
9     search
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using inner join.

```
 update tag  inner join tag2
 on tag.id = tag2.id     
 set tag.name = tag2.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update tag t1
inner join tag2 on t1.id= t2.id set t1.name=t2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update tag t, tag2 t2 
set t.name=t2.name
where t.id=t2.id
```